# Can someone explain these lines of code for jumping in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This line of code is what makes my character jump in my game but I don't really understand it. It works however I just want to understand it better

```
self.jumpCount = 8

self.IsJump = False

    if not(self.IsJump):

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.IsJump = True
            self.Left = True
            self.Right = False
            self.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if self.jumpCount >= -8:
            neg =1
            if self.jumpCount < 0:
                neg= -1
            self.y-=(self.jumpCount **2)*.5 *neg
            self.jumpCount-= 1

        else:
            self.IsJump = False
            self.jumpCount = 8
```

Comment: Can you please format the code correctly so that we can read it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your initial else statement is outside of the "if not(self.IsJump):" conditional.

Since self.IsJump is set to False, your conditional, if not(self.IsJump):, will execute. This sets isJump to true and hence why I'm assuming your character jumps. The else statement is not executed.

Comment: when the if not statement is executed then i press the key 'w' will i then be going to the else statement?

Comment: since it will change self.IsJump to True?

Comment: in the case, the code is wrong since the else statement is not executed if the initial if statement always runs true first